# how to parse file that can have CR|LF or LF in linux using regex in cpp

Tags: regex

I have file that may contain only LF or both CR|LF. I want to parse this file using regex in my cpp program running in linux environment.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Use `\r?$` to match end of line.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. Don't expect others to write code for you.